# How do I merge the output from 2 separate temp tables into a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, temp-tables

I am using `SQL Server 2012` and I have 2 separate `T-SQL` queries which I am trying to merge as a single query.

Query 1:

```
   USE MyDatabase
   SELECT [Col A], [Col B], [Col C]
   INTO #TempTable
   FROM MyList
   WHERE [Date] >= '2018-01-01'

   SELECT * FROM #TempTable

   PIVOT(SUM([Col B]) 
   FOR [Col A] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])) AS PVTTable
```

Query 2:

```
   USE MyDatabase
   SELECT [Col A], [Col B], [Col C]
   INTO #TempTable2
   FROM MyList
   WHERE [StayDate] >= '2018-01-01'
   AND [DateCreated] <= '2018-01-27'

  SELECT * FROM #TempTable2

  PIVOT(SUM([Col B]) 
   FOR [Col A] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])) AS PVTTable
```

I have tried using the `UNION ALL` syntax, as follows:

```
   USE MyDatabase
   SELECT [Col A], [Col B], [Col C]
   INTO #TempTable
   FROM MyList
   WHERE [StayDate] >= '2018-01-01'

   PIVOT(SUM([Col B]) 
   FOR [Col A] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])) AS PVTTable


   UNION ALL

   SELECT [Col A], [Col B], [Col C]
   INTO #TempTable2
   FROM MyList
   WHERE [StayDate] >= '2018-01-01'
   AND [DateCreated] <= '2018-01-27'

   PIVOT(SUM([Col B]) 
   FOR [Col A] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])) AS PVTTable
```

My objective is to merge the 2 pivot results as one single output table. However, this is not working! How do I re-write this query?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and your expected output?

Comment: If you want one table then why are you using two tables?

Comment: Do your queries actually work?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No they don't! I have updated them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this in one table, you would have only one `into` in the query.  For `UNION ALL` this is in the first query:

```
   SELECT [Col A], [Col B], [Col C]
   INTO #TempTable
   FROM MyList
   WHERE [StayDate] >= '2018-01-01'

   PIVOT(SUM([Col B]) 
   FOR [Col A] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])) AS PVTTable
   UNION ALL    
   SELECT [Col A], [Col B], [Col C]
   FROM MyList
   WHERE [StayDate] >= '2018-01-01'
   AND [DateCreated] <= '2018-01-27'

   PIVOT(SUM([Col B]) 
   FOR [Col A] IN ([Jan], [Feb], [Mar], [Apr], [May], [Jun], [Jul], [Aug], [Sep], [Oct], [Nov], [Dec])) AS PVTTable;
```

That said, I don't think your queries work.  This answer only addresses the syntax question about saving data to one table.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have updated the part related to the pivot construct in my queries. I will give your solution a try.